# What's a Listener's subject in Reactor?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I've a simple Listener pattern implementation which (in a condensed form) looks like this:

```
public class EmailProducer implements Runnable {
    private List<Consumer<EmailMessage>> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    private IdleManager idleManager;

    public void registerListener(Consumer<EmailMessage> listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void run() {
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
        idleManager = new IdleManager(session, Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
        // use IMAP IDLE to listen for new incoming emails
        Folder inbox = openInbox();
        inbox.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountAdapter() {
            public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent ev) {
                Message[] msgs = ev.getMessages();
                for (Message msg : msgs) {
                    EmailMessage info = EmailMessage.from(msg);
                    for (Consumer<EmailMessage> listener : listeners) {
                        listener.accept(info);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        try {
            idleManager.watch(inbox);
        catch (FolderClosedException|StoreClosedException ex) {
            run(); // restart, need to re-establish connection
        }
    }
}
```

So in essence this grabs email from my inbox, extracts information from each email and converts that into an internal message format.

A typical `Consumer` would then persist that message, another would display the information on a HTML page, and yet another might trigger 3rd party systems to do some action. All of this works fine.

Now, I'm trying to get some more resiliency in face of a `Consumer` failure. For example, I want my `EmailMessage` to live on if the persistence consumer failed (threw an exception), ending processing. In that case, I want processing to be retried after a pause interval. Right now, if a Consumer fails, the message would be lost.

I recently found out about Reactor, and I think it's orchestration would save the message and enable me to do what I need. However, I fail to see how I would adapt my current `Runnable` into it's model. From the [documentation](http://projectreactor.io/docs/reference/#_ringbuffer_processors) it seems like I need a `RingBufferProcessor` to hold my messages. I can't find another way then to pass the processor to my `Runnable` for it call the `onNext()` method instead of the separate listener's `accept` method(s). Am I missing something or is this the way it's supposed to work?

(Extra cookies for showing me how I retry in the face of consumer failure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might take a look at the [`RingBufferProcessor`](http://projectreactor.io/docs/reference/#core-rbp) which will allows you to do parallel tasks with a single `EmailMessage`. You'd set it up something like:

```
ReactorProcessor<Message, Message> processor = RingBufferProcessor.share("email-processor", 1024);
Stream<Message> s = Streams.wrap(processor);

s.consume(m -> firstTask(m));
s.consume(m -> secondTask(m));
s.consume(m -> thirdTask(m));
```

This will parallelize the work onto 3 separate threads (1 per `Consumer`). To do retries or capture errors, you'd need either `Stream.retry` or `Stream.retryWhen` (for backoff) or just `Stream.when` (which doesn't give you the message that caused the error).

```
s.retry(t -> t instanceof IllegalStateException)
 .consume(m -> retryMessage(m));

s.when(NumberFormatException.class, e -> e.printStackTrace());
```

Then to publish messages to this `Processor`, just call `onNext`:

```
for(EmailMessage msg : msgs) {
    processor.onNext(msg);
}
```

Comment: Finally found some time to implement this, thanks! I opted to keep the `Producer` with a `Consumer` list because it's a separate product from the one using reactor now, but a simple `producer.registerListener(processor::onNext)` should do the job just fine.